# Is it possible to use inspect element to find when a account is created?

Tags: database, dataframe, date, inspect-element

Hi I am trying to gather some information for a data base project. And I am trying to organize all my account by the MM/DD/Year they where created. I can find all the info for website like facebook easily but I am having trouble with site such as Ticketmaster when it only show the "fan since YYYY. Is there a method to look up when the account was created by using inspect element or any code ?

Comment: Websites aren't required to provide this information (as far as I know). If your question is specific to Ticketmaster, then make that clear, and attempt a solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.